# Array Element Position Java

Tags: java, arrays, position

Are there any other ways to print the position of your element inside the array?
Even[position in the array]=even numbers
Odd[position in the array]=odd numbers

```
public class samt {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int Num[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        int ctr=1, ctr2=0;
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            if(Num[i]%2==0) {       
                System.out.print("Even"+"["+ctr+"]=");
                System.out.println(Num[i]);
                ctr+=2;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            if(Num[i]%2!=0) {
                System.out.print("Odd"+"["+ctr2+"]=");
                System.out.println(Num[i]);
                ctr2+=2;
            }   
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: Yes, there are other ways. Are you looking for anything specific? In other words: Why are you looking for an alternative? Does it have to be more performant, more consice or something else?

Comment: just want to make it shorter.  all my codes are long I'm trying things to shorten and apply those to my other codes. any will do

Comment: Hey you can just place a else clause in your first for loop. In this clause you can place the odd output. You only have even or odd numbers. The second for loop is no longer needed. This will half your runtime, what is not relevant on array with 10 entries but still.

Comment: @Tr1monster I think your scheme is wrong, that doesn't print the odd and even numbers separately, they are output alternately,that does not meet the needs of the user

Comment: @时间只会一直走 fair point. I do not look at this aspect of the code. If it is acceptable to get the output at the end of the algorithm you can use two `StringBuilder` and print the result at the end.

Comment: @Tr1monster nice try！ i am still thinking about how to move the cursor up a line!

Answer (score 1):

If your only goal is to shorten your code you can use lists and filter for even and odd numbers:

```
Integer[] num = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(num);
List<Integer> even = list.stream().filter(n -> n % 2 == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> odd = list.stream().filter(n -> n % 2 == 1).collect(Collectors.toList());
even.forEach(n -> System.out.println("Even" + "["+ list.indexOf(n) + "]=" + n));
odd.forEach(n -> System.out.println("Odd" + "["+ list.indexOf(n) + "]=" + n));
```

With this the output lookes the same as with your code:

```
Even[1]=2
Even[3]=4
Even[5]=6
Even[7]=8
Even[9]=10
Odd[0]=1
Odd[2]=3
Odd[4]=5
Odd[6]=7
Odd[8]=9
```

Note that the runtime of this is probably longer than with your attempt.